# Algorithm - if known $x$ and $y$ value

Tags: algorithms

I am new to this site, so please bear with my bad question-writing skills!

I was given a puzzle, in which I have to work the algorithm being used to generate the $y$ value from the $x$ value. Here are the given 'rules':

The variable $x$ has $2$ digits

> if $x = 19, y = 45$
>
> if $x = 10, y = 50$
>
> if $x = 15, y = 25$
>
> EDIT: if $x = 65, y = 55$

What might the algorithm be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y = a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x+a_0.$ Then we have the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
19^3 a_3 + 19^2 a_2 + 19 a_1 + a_0 &= 45, \\
10^3 a_3 + 10^2 a_2 + 10 a_1 + a_0 &= 50, \\
15^3 a_3 + 15^2 a_2 + 15 a_1 + a_0 &= 25, \\
65^3 a_3 + 65^2 a_2 + 65 a_1 + a_0 &= 55,
\end{align*}
$$
forming the linear system

$$\begin{pmatrix}
19^3 & 19^2 & 19 & 1 \\
10^3 & 10^2 & 10 & 1 \\
15^3 & 15^2 & 15 & 1 \\
65^3 & 65^2 & 65 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_3 \\ a_2 \\ a_1 \\ a_0
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
45 \\ 50 \\25 \\ 55
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Solving, we find

$$y \approx -0.0219x^3+2.0765x^2-46.491x+329.1989.$$

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but this algorithm isn't going to be as clever as that!

Comment: A polynomial interpolant is like the least clever thing out there ;)

Answer (score 1):

What are the rules?

If the one's place number is nonzero, multiply it by 5 for the result. If the one's place number is zero, multiply the whole number by 5 for the result.

This can likely be stated in a much better way.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is a problem with this. I just realised that is x = 65, y = 55

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

$$
x\equiv 1 \pmod{2} \Leftrightarrow y=5\cdot(x \pmod{10})
$$
$$
x\equiv 0 \pmod{2} \Leftrightarrow y=5x
$$
**EDIT:** The following is only theorizing.
$$
x > 50 \Rightarrow y=5\cdot(x \pmod{10})+\frac {x-(x \pmod{10})}{2}
$$
Now transform it to a function:

$$
f(x) = \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{l l}
     5\cdot(x \pmod{10}) & \quad x\equiv 1 \pmod{2}\\
     5x & \quad x\equiv 0 \pmod{2}
   \end{array} \right.
$$

Comment: I suppose it would be helpful if we had one more example of an even x to see if the condition was parity or a zero, but your interpretation seems much more likely.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is a problem with this. I just realised that is x = 65, y = 55

Comment: @ultimatetechie: Why do you not have written that in the question?

Comment: @Doop I am so sorry for not stating this

Comment: @Zeonatra Because I just asked my friend who gave it to me for that. I can try and get anther number if you want?

Comment: @Doop I can get another number; Which is best do you think (Rules: 2 digit). Should it be even?